# How does Gun js connect with peers on a deployed app?

Tags: javascript, svelte, gun

I am new to using Gun js and am currently getting familiar with it. There is a great tutorial on YouTube by fireship: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5x3OMXjgMc About building a simple chat app.

My simple/stupid question is that how can a deployed app like this exactly sync data between its users with simply creating a gun instance and then putting some data `gun.get('key').put(data)` on the database. How does it find its users with no given connection?